# Java Precedence - Casting and Bitwise Operators

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operators, operator-precedence

I am having a hard time understanding some code that shows an example how a double in Java could be transformed into a byte[] and vice versa.

Here is the code being used to transform a double into a byte[]:

```
public static byte [] doubleToByteArray (double numDouble)
{
    byte [] arrayByte = new byte [8];
    long numLong;

    // Takes the double and sticks it into a long, without changing it
    numLong = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(numDouble);

    // Then we need to isolate each byte
    // The casting of byte (byte), captures only the 8 rightmost bytes
    arrayByte[0] = (byte)(numLong >>> 56);
    arrayByte[1] = (byte)(numLong >>> 48);
    arrayByte[2] = (byte)(numLong >>> 40);
    arrayByte[3] = (byte)(numLong >>> 32);
    arrayByte[4] = (byte)(numLong >>> 24);
    arrayByte[5] = (byte)(numLong >>> 16);
    arrayByte[6] = (byte)(numLong >>> 8);
    arrayByte[7] = (byte)numLong;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayByte.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("arrayByte[" + i + "] = " + arrayByte[i]);
    }

    return arrayByte;
}
```

And here is the code being used to tranform the byte[] back to a double:

```
public static double byteArrayToDouble (byte [] arrayByte)
{
    double numDouble;
    long numLong;

    // When putting byte into long, java also adds the sign 
    // However, we don't want to put bits that are not from the orignal value
    // 
    // The rightmost bits left unaltered because we "and" them with a 1
    // The left bits become 0 because we "and" them with a 0
    //
    // We are applying a "mask" (& 0x00 ... FFL)
    // 0 & 0 = 0
    // 0 & 1 = 0
    // 1 & 0 = 0
    // 1 & 1 = 1
    //
    // So, the expression will put byte in the long (puts it into the right most position)
    // Then we apply mask to remove the sign applied by java
    // Then we move the byte into its position (shift left 56 bits, then 48 bits, etc.)
    // We end up with 8 longs, that each have a byte set up in the appropriate position
    // By doing an | with each one of them, we combine them all into the orignal long
    //
    // Then we use Double.longBitsToDouble, to convert the long bytes into double.
    numLong = (((long)arrayByte[0] & 0x00000000000000FFL) << 56) | (((long)arrayByte[1] & 0x00000000000000FFL) << 48) |
        (((long)arrayByte[2] & 0x00000000000000FFL) << 40) |    (((long)arrayByte[3] & 0x00000000000000FFL) << 32) |
        (((long)arrayByte[4] & 0x00000000000000FFL) << 24) | (((long)arrayByte[5] & 0x00000000000000FFL) << 16) |
        (((long)arrayByte[6] & 0x00000000000000FFL) <<  8) | ((long)arrayByte[7] & 0x00000000000000FFL);

    numDouble = Double.longBitsToDouble(numLong);

    return numDouble;
}
```

Okay, and here is the part I don't quite get.

```
((long)arrayByte[0] & 0x00000000000000FFL) << 56
```

It seems as though the casting happens before the actual bitwise operation, because the author says that

> the expression will put byte in the long [...] Then we apply mask to remove the sign applied by java

How come the byte is being transformed into a long before it being actually casted? Shouldn't the operation resemble this?

```
(((long)arrayByte[0]) & 0x00000000000000FFL) << 56
```

Or is there something else I don't understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to how operator precedence and associativity works in Java.<sup>1</sup>

Unfortunately, the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) provides only a partial overview, and the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2) is not of great help either, as it mostly leaves the exercise of figuring out operator precedence to the reader by stating:

> Precedence among operators is managed by a hierarchy of grammar productions.

In general, expressions are evaluated from left to right. In terms of operator precedence, the following table<sup>2</sup>  applies:

```
╔═══════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ Level ║ Operator     ║ Description          ║ Associativity   ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 16    ║ []           ║ access array element ║ left to right   ║
║       ║ .            ║ access object member ║                 ║
║       ║ ()           ║ parentheses          ║                 ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 15    ║ ++           ║ unary post-increment ║ not associative ║
║       ║ --           ║ unary post-decrement ║                 ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 14    ║ ++           ║ unary pre-increment  ║ right to left   ║
║       ║ --           ║ unary pre-decrement  ║                 ║
║       ║ +            ║ unary plus           ║                 ║
║       ║ -            ║ unary minus          ║                 ║
║       ║ !            ║ unary logical NOT    ║                 ║
║       ║ ~            ║ unary bitwise NOT    ║                 ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 13    ║ ()           ║ cast                 ║ right to left   ║
║       ║ new          ║ object creation      ║                 ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 12    ║ *            ║ multiplicative       ║ left to right   ║
║       ║ /            ║                      ║                 ║
║       ║ %            ║                      ║                 ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 11    ║ + -          ║ additive             ║ left to right   ║
║       ║ +            ║ string concatenation ║                 ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 10    ║ << >>        ║ shift                ║ left to right   ║
║       ║ >>>          ║                      ║                 ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 9     ║ < <=         ║ relational           ║ not associative ║
║       ║ > >=         ║                      ║                 ║
║       ║ instanceof   ║                      ║                 ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 8     ║ ==           ║ equality             ║ left to right   ║
║       ║ !=           ║                      ║                 ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 7     ║ &            ║ bitwise AND          ║ left to right   ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 6     ║ ^            ║ bitwise XOR          ║ left to right   ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 5     ║ |            ║ bitwise OR           ║ left to right   ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 4     ║ &&           ║ logical AND          ║ left to right   ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 3     ║ ||           ║ logical OR           ║ left to right   ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 2     ║ ?:           ║ ternary              ║ right to left   ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1     ║ = += -=      ║ assignment           ║ right to left   ║
║       ║ *= /= %=     ║                      ║                 ║
║       ║ &= ^= |=     ║                      ║                 ║
║       ║ <<= >>= >>>= ║                      ║                 ║
╚═══════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

For your specific question, this means that no extra parentheses need to be placed around the cast operation, as the precedence of the cast operator `()` is higher than that of the bitwise AND `&` operator (level 13 vs. level 7).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I wrote this up as a canonical answer to address questions about operator precedence and associativity in Java. I found a lot of existing answers that gave partial information, but I couldn't find one that gave an overview of the complete precedence and associativity table.

<sup>2</sup> Operator precedence and associativiy table reproduced from https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/.</sup>